# Using TLS 1.2 with C#.Net Winform App and SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, tls1.2

We have an internal C#.Net WinForm application which is installed on users machine and connects to a SQL Server 2008 database. We have had a security review which identified that communications sent back to the application from the database was in plain-text, so could be intercepted by sniffing tools.

What steps would I need to take to ensure the WinForm app used TLS 1.2 protocol to communicate with the database?

Comment: Take a look at ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol. This may do what you need.

Comment: The security review didn't identify that you use an *unsupported* database version? You can connect to SQL Server using SSL, but *TLS1.2* requires .NET 4.5.2 *at least* on the client side. You have to *enable* encrypted connections on the server. Check [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: @Wheels73 this has nothing to do with database connections.

Comment: There is a [Microsoft KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1.2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server) that explains what patches you need to install to enable TLS1.2 all the way back to 2008

Comment: Also check the [ConnectionString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation. You need to set `Encrypted=true` in your connection string and probably `TrustServerCertificate` too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The DBAs ruled out SSL as apparantly this would need to be applied at the server level and there are many production databases on the same box.

Comment: @Jonno then you permanenty fail the audit. TLS1.2 **is an SSL** protocol. You can't ask for encryption but don't want encryption yet still want encryption. Have the DBA ask for a fix at `dba.stackexchange.com` and watch

Comment: Anyway - TLS1.2 on SQL Server, you have the official patch list, you have the official documentation and requirements for it. Forward them to the DBAs, PMs and auditors and let them fight it out. The PMs may decide that they don't care about the security review after all

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Yeah realized that after.. I used it for connections to web services. Didn't quite read the post right... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Panagiotis Kanavos' comments, I did the following to use TLS 1.2:

- Confirm SP3 was installed on SQL Server 2008.
- Upgrade winform app to .NET 4.5.2
- Set Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=true to connection string